# How to use a html5 color input type but without using a javascript color picker in wicket framework?

Tags: html, wicket

In the wicket application, I want to use a html5 colorpicker. How can I achieve this?

I expect the output of the html5 color input type as fig.1 [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Dzke.png), but the actual output is fig.2.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJ9RB.png)

Comment: Actually, I want to use a system-dependent color picker using html5 in wicket application dynamically. Please help me in this as I am new to the Wicket framework.

Answer (score 1):

Colour inputs use whatever user interface the browser provides, often the native colour picker UI from the operating system / desktop environment.

You can't control this without reimplementing the entire UI in JavaScript.

Comment: Can you help me with an example of using native color picker UI html5?